# Javascript animations in timed sequence

Tags: javascript, css, svg, snap.svg

I am manipulating a couple CSS classes with Javascript. My script is on a timed sequence, which all together plays an animation. I feel like I am close, but I am stuck, any insights?

Essentially, I need Step 1 and Step 2 to go together at the same time for duration of one second, Step 3 to go for duration of one second after Step 1 and 2, Step 4 and Step 5 to go together at the same time for duration of one second after Step 1, 2, 3 and 4....etc. At the end of Step 6, reset timer and repeat.

I have an SVG, which is made up of a bunch of lines. Some of these lines have to "turn on" at a certain time in the sequence, some have to get bigger, so I'm toggling their classes but only during that certain time, otherwise they are off.

This is what my code looks like (simple SVG is just a model for demonstration). It will manually add classes to elements, but won't reset its timer and repeat infinitely because I haven't been able to figure out how to clear the classes after I add them:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
      #line1, #line2, #line3, #line4, #line5, #line6 {
          visiblity: hidden;
      }

      .showElement {
          visibility: visible !important;
      }   

      .growElement {
          transform: scale(1.5) perspective(1px);
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<svg height="210" width="500">
  <line id="line1" class="first" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:2" />
  <line id="line2" class="first" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="300" style="stroke:orange;stroke-width:2" />
  <line id="line3" class="second" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="400" style="stroke:yellow;stroke-width:2" />
  <line id="line4" class="third" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="500" style="stroke:green;stroke-width:2" />
  <line id="line5" class="fourth" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="600" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:2" />
  <line id="line6" class="fifth" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="700" style="stroke:purple;stroke-width:2" />
  <line id="line7" class="sixth" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="800" style="stroke:pink;stroke-width:2" />
</svg>

<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

            setInterval(function() {
                // create array of all the elements with the class 'first', loop over each one
                // in this case, ['
                var firstClass = document.getElementsByClassName("first");
                console.log(firstClass[0]);
                console.log(firstClass[1]);
                setInterval(function(){
                    firstClass[0].classList.add("showElement");
                    firstClass[1].classList.add("showElement");
                }, 1000);

                var secondClass = document.getElementsByClassName("second");
                console.log(secondClass[0]);
                console.log(secondClass[1]);
                setInterval(function(){
                    secondClass[0].classList.add("showElement");
                    secondClass[1].classList.add("showElement");
                }, 2000);

                var thirdClass = document.getElementsByClassName("third");
                console.log(thirdClass[0]);
                setInterval(function(){
                    thirdClass[0].classList.add("showElement");
                }, 3000);

                var fourthClass = document.getElementsByClassName("fourth");
                console.log(fourthClass[0]);
                setInterval(function(){
                    fourthClass[0].classList.add("showElement");
                }, 4000);
            }, 4000);
     });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I also need to figure out how to add multiple classes at once, for only some steps. For example, element .first, .second and .third I want to suddenly appear so I give them .showElement, but element .third I want to also add .growElement. How do I do that?

This is my Javascript code, that doesn't accept multiple things in tandem. It uses a counter, so not as gnarly looking as the previous. It looks through every item in the list and applies one style:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var connections = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth'];
    var i = 0; // index of the first item to show


    setInterval(function(){
        console.log(connections[i]);
        document.getElementsByClassName(connections[i]).classList.add("showElement");

        var counter = connections[i++];  // get the current item index and increment
        if ((i == connections.length)) {
            i = 0; // reset to first element if reach the end
        }
    }, 1000);

});
```

Note: I am not looking to use jQuery, just pure JavaScript. This animation exists on a single page web site with no other JavaScript with an external SVG, so it must exist inside the SVG file, and I don't see much point in installing a large library.

But I am looking into possible better ways to solve this problem. Someone told me this is the work of 'promises'. I am researching Snap.svg, Q, When, WinJS and RSVP.js libraries right now, and would welcome a suggestion if you thought it'd be better (even jQuery, if it truly is easier).

Comment: just clarifying how you want it to run.

at one second add showElement to all elements with className one.

do you want that showElement to persist then for the full 6 seconds at which it is removed from everything and repeated...

or only for the initial 1 second and then removed.

Comment: Yes, exactly as you describe it. It can persist for the full 6 seconds...that is the only way I have gotten it to work so far. Ideally it'd only persist for the 1 second then be removed.

Comment: so ideally in a time map like this can you show me how it should run

 `1: 1 `  
 `2: 2`  
 `3: 3`

where it is seconds elapsed: elements shown, i.e. what elements are shown at what point in time.

Comment: Seems to me this would be a lot easier in SMIL where you can chain animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little cleaner version which does the animations on a 1-second interval and gives you a little more obvious control over what's happening on each frame.

For adding multiple classes, you can add whatever you like all at once like: `classList.Add('showElement', 'growElement')` (and the same goes for removing. [See examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList))

Animation will repeat on a loop by setting the frame back to 0 in the last frame (0 because the frame counter increments after the switch statement). Then in the first frame make sure to clear the styles from the last frame.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
      #line1, #line2, #line3, #line4, #line5, #line6, #line7 {
        visibility: hidden;
        transform: scale(1) perspective(1);
        transition: .5s transform;
      }

      .showElement {
          visibility: visible !important;
      }   

      .growElement {
          transform: scale(3.5) perspective(1px);
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
  
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <line id="line1" class="first" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:2" />
  <line id="line2" class="first" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="300" style="stroke:orange;stroke-width:2" />
  <line id="line3" class="second" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="400" style="stroke:yellow;stroke-width:2" />
  <line id="line4" class="third" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="500" style="stroke:green;stroke-width:2" />
  <line id="line5" class="fourth" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="600" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:2" />
  <line id="line6" class="fifth" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="700" style="stroke:purple;stroke-width:2" />
  <line id="line7" class="sixth" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="800" style="stroke:pink;stroke-width:2" />
</svg>

<script>
                
var frame = 1;

// create array of all the elements with the class 'first', loop over each one
// in this case, ['
var firstClass = document.getElementsByClassName("first");
var secondClass = document.getElementsByClassName("second");
var thirdClass = document.getElementsByClassName("third");
var fourthClass = document.getElementsByClassName("fourth");
var fifthClass = document.getElementsByClassName("fifth");
var sixthClass = document.getElementsByClassName("sixth");
var seventhClass = document.getElementsByClassName("seventh");

function hideUnusedClasses(p_classesArray) {
  p_classesArray.forEach(function(array, index){
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;++i) {
      array[i].classList.remove('showElement', 'growElement');
    }
  });
}

var interval = setInterval(function(){
  //console.log('Run every 1 second');
  switch(frame) {
    case 1:
      //console.log('frame', frame);
      hideUnusedClasses([sixthClass]);
      for(var i=0;i<firstClass.length;++i) { 
        firstClass[i].classList.add('showElement');
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      //console.log('frame', frame);
      //console.log('Delete 1 class');
      hideUnusedClasses([firstClass]); 
      for(var i=0;i<secondClass.length;++i) {
        secondClass[i].classList.add('showElement');
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      //console.log('frame', frame);
      //console.log('Delete 2 class');
      hideUnusedClasses([secondClass]);
      for(var i=0;i<thirdClass.length;++i) {
        thirdClass[i].classList.add('showElement', 'growElement');
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      //console.log('frame', frame);
      hideUnusedClasses([thirdClass]);
      //console.log('Delete 3 class');
      for(var i=0;i<fourthClass.length;++i) {
        fourthClass[i].classList.add('showElement');
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      //console.log('frame', frame);
      hideUnusedClasses([fourthClass]);
      for(var i=0;i<fifthClass.length;++i) {
        fifthClass[i].classList.add('showElement');
      }
      break;
    case 6:
      //console.log('frame', frame);
      hideUnusedClasses([fifthClass]);
      for(var i=0;i<sixthClass.length;++i) {
        sixthClass[i].classList.add('showElement');
      }
      frame = 0;
      break;  
    default:
      //console.log('all done');
      //clearInterval(interval);
  }
  ++frame;
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. Do you know how to put it on an infinite loop? So that after the last class is animated, it repeats to the first class?

Comment: Updated the code to make it loop - just have to reset the frames at the end of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var connections = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth'];

function showElements(i,duration){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(connections[i]); 
    elements.map((e) =>  e.classList.add('showElement'))
    setTimeout(()=>{
        //remove the .showElement after duration to display has elapsed
        elements.map((e)=> e.classList.remove('showElement'))
        //recursively calls the next animation to be played, resets at 6
        showElements((i+1)%6,duration)
    },duration)        
}
```

Not sure if this is how exactly how you want it but it will add showElement to each for duration and then remove it.

```
showElements(0,1000)
```